# shifting array elements in bulk- matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have three arrays longitude, latitudes, height of the same length. Height array is a function of latitude and longitude. The structure is simple, each latitude value (e.g. 85.00) has corresponding height values for 0-360 longitudes. To make it simple, here is how the original data looks like:

```
longitude     latitude      height
  0.00         -90.00         5
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00         -90.00         7
  0.00         -89.00         9
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00         -89.00         14
    .            .            .
\\similar pattern until 90.00..
  0.00          90.00         3
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00          90.00         14
```

I want my latitude array from 90.00 to -90.00 instead of -90.00 to 90.00 and consequently height array will be changed. And for that it is clear that I have to move sections of height array. How do I achieve that? Is it possible just with array operation? Or do I need a loop?

This is how I want it to be as an output

```
  0.00          90.00         3
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00          90.00         14
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
  0.00         -89.00         9
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00         -89.00         14
  0.00         -90.00         5
    .            .            .
    .            .            .
360.00         -90.00         7
```

Note: A single latitude, corresponding 0-to-360 longitude, has 10800 (height) values. Total length is 58320000

I hope I am clear enough

Comment: I'm confused. How many elements are in each array and how many elements are in each block. (I think each block is the number of repeated latitude values or the range in `height` between the `5` and the `7` at the top of the example?)

Comment: **elements in array: 58320000**, **elements in a block: 10800**, meaning there are 5400 such blocks. in the latitude array, each block contains repeated value until 0.00 longitude is encountered. height values are varying, there is no range, above mentioned `5` and `7` is just for sake of example.

Comment: Okay, see if my answer is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a column vector `A`, divided into blocks of size `blkSize`, you can reverse the order of the blocks (keeping the order within the blocks the same) like this:

```
m = numel(A);
B = reshape(flipud(reshape(flipud(A),blkSize,[])),m,1)
```

Example:

```
A = [1 2 3  4 5 6  7 8 9  10 11 12  13 14 15  16 17 18].';
blkSize = 3;

B.' = 16 17 18  13 14 15  10 11 12  7 8 9  4 5 6  1 2 3
```

(Input and output transposed for brevity.)

Comment: dang! out of memory issue. I'll try on a better machine tomorrow! But I think, this should work, because I was also trying first to use `flipud` and then use it again in a loop!